# command execution in linux

Tags: linux, command-line

Is it possible to avoid sequential command execution in Linux? 
For eg: I can enter a command ' echo "hello";ls ' . This command will execute by printing "Hello" and then listing the directory. Is possible to make only one command execute at a time,that is only echo command should work blocking 'ls'.

Comment: That's called sequential execution ;)

Comment: What's wrong with omitting the ";ls"?

Comment: `command1; command2` literally means "execute command1, then execute command2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called sequential execution (which is what you want, but want to avoid at the same time?).

It might look like both are occuring at once, but they are occuring sequentially.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid sequential execution?

Comment: That's called multitasking, then.